# CakePHP - Passing an array of record IDs to paginate - is it possible?

Tags: cakephp

Due to having to having to import data from an old non cake app and oddly built database table I need to pass paginate an array of records it is allowed to display - is this possible?

Normally I would reorganise the data into proper relationships etc but due to time scales etc this is not possible.

To give you more info - in my users table I have a field that contains a list of ID's that relate to documents they are allowed to view. The field will contain something like

```
123,23,45,56,765,122,11.9,71,25
```

Each ID refers to a document the documents model. I know that normally you would create proper ACOs and AROs and let the ACL/Auth componant handle which users can access what but this isnt an option this time around. So I thought if I could do it via paginate/find it might be an option?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't pass it a list of IDs, you'd use the IDs in your paginate conditions - something like below.

(Code written off top of my head, so pardon any syntax errors...etc.  It should give you the right idea/path at least):

```
//Controller
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->loadModel('Document');

$user = $this->User->findById($userId);

$documentIds = explode(',', $user['User']['doc_ids']);

$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $documentIds
    )
));
$documents = $this->paginate('Document');
```

When you pass an array as a condtion (eg. `'id'=>$arrayOfIds`), it uses MySQLs "IN" - something like:

```
... WHERE id IN (45, 92, 173)
```

Comment: @tigrang - I do - that's what I wrote.  ;)